# The term Get-PnPAzureADUser is not recognized as the name of a Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a PnP Power shell script, but it is raising this error:-

```
The term Get-PnPAzureADUser is not recognized as the name of a Cmdlet
```

any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Get-PnPAzureADUser** is part of the [**PnP.PowerShell** module.](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/)

If you are using the legacy module, first uninstall it:

```
Uninstall-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

Then, install the latest PnP.PowerShell module

```
Install-module PnP.PowerShell
```